# How can I filter some very complicated looking JSON data and use it for markers in leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, json, filter, maps, leaflet

I get my data from the Austin, Texas public data sets. Here's the filtered raw data, downloadable in .json format I want to use...

https://data.austintexas.gov/dataset/New100/4ehx-iwqv

Now, I've figured out how to use a .json file to create markers, but I have so much data in the .json file it would take far too many hours than I have to make all of the 165 I need to make. How can I filter this so that the .leaflet markers only use the information I need? I specifically need to filter for name, latitude, and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with leaf.js, but it sounds like you want to take a json file and trim the contents of each of its objects. If that's the case, I would write a script that loads the json file, filters out the attributes you don't need by looping through each object one by one, then write the contents to a new json file.

You can use any programming language you'd like. Python has a nice json module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

This is actually less complicated than it looks. In the object you have two main properties: `meta` & `data`. Data is an array containing arrays with the different locations and their corresponding data. It's just a matter of counting which array items you need, You need the eight element, it contains the name. The twelvth element contains the array with the coordinates at position one and two. Best explained with some code:

```
// Your data url 
var url = 'https://data.austintexas.gov/api/views/4ehx-iwqv/rows.json';

// Fetch the JSON with XHR (Using jQuery here)
$.getJSON(url, function (response) {
    // Loop over the data array
    response.data.forEach(function (item) {
        // create new object 
        var data = {
            // Array element 8 contains the name
            'name': item[8],
            // Array element 12 contains address array
            'latitude': item[12][1], // Element 1 in address, the latitude
            'longitude': item[12][2] // Element 2 in address, the longitude
        };
        // Create marker with latitude and longitude from data object
        var marker = L.marker([
            data.latitude,
            data.longitude
        ]);
        // Bind popup with name properties of data object
        marker.bindPopup('<h4>' + data.name + '</h4>');
        // Add marker to map
        marker.addTo(map);
    });
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fe7YKE?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I could potentially do it outside of using Python, right? Just with leaflet.js?